# How to prevent actionbar tabs showing as to drop down list?

Tags: android, android-tabs

Trying to play with default project actionbar+tabs, created by ADT plugin.
On some devices tabs moved to drop-down list after screen rotation.

Android developer guide [says](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html):

> **Note:** In some cases, the Android system will show your action bar tabs as a drop-down list in order to ensure the best fit in the action bar.

But if I want to disable this feature, and show always tabs, there is a right way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to do it, AFAIK. I [filed an issue on this very point](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=24439) and was told that it was working as designed.

The simplest solution, IMHO, is to not use action bar tabs, but instead switch to `ViewPager` and tabs for it (`PagerTabStrip`, tabbed indicator from ViewPagerIndicator, etc.).

Answer (score 2):

You should add the following line after adding tabs.

```
actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS); //Important! Must be after all .addTab
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint! This works perfectly! However the hint `Important! Must be after all .addTab` should be more distinct. I did not recognized it on first view and since I did use `actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS)` before adding the tabs I did not see the solution here. Using this AFTER .addTab is realy the key!