# Android 4+ actionbar tabs showing as to drop down list on first launch - To to prevent?

Tags: java, android, tabs, android-actionbar

I am working on an Android 4+ app that uses an ActionBar Tabs to navigate an `android.support.v4.view.ViewPager`. This works fine, except when the app is launched the very first time after installation. In this case the tabs are displayed as drop down list instead.

This it the layout of the MainActivity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>  

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"        
        style="@style/NavigationDrawerListView" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/right_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        style="@style/ShortcutsListView" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

With the init code MainActivity.java

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...

    // TabBar
    sectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(sectionsPagerAdapter);

    currentPageIndex = (savedInstanceState != null ? savedInstanceState.getInt(CURRENT_PAGE_INDEX_KEY, -1) : -1 );
    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            getActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(position);             
            updateCurrentPageIndex(position);
        }
    });

    // ActionBar
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    ActionBar.TabListener tabListener = new ActionBar.TabListener() {
        public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction arg1) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        public void onTabReselected(Tab arg0, android.app.FragmentTransaction arg1) { }
        public void onTabUnselected(Tab arg0, android.app.FragmentTransaction arg1) { }
    };

    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab()
            .setText(R.string.MainPageTitle)
            .setTabListener(tabListener));
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab()
            .setText(R.string.ContactsPageTitle)
            .setTabListener(tabListener));
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab()
            .setText(R.string.SettingsPageTitle)
            .setTabListener(tabListener));
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab()
            .setText(R.string.MessagePageTitle)
            .setTabListener(tabListener));


    // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14672984/
    // Set NavigationMode AFTER alle tabs have been added
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    ...
}
```

As far as I can tell the the first launch is really the only difference here. But I have no idea how this influences the tabs.

Any idea how to allways use tabs and never drop down list?

Answer (score 1):

> Any idea how to allways use tabs and never drop down list?

First, action bar tabs were deprecated a year ago.

Second, [you have never had control whether action bar tabs show up as tabs versus a drop-down list](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=24439).

I suggest that you use some other tab solution, whether that is `TabLayout` from the SDK's Design Support library, [third-party tabs associated with a `ViewPager`](http://android-arsenal.com/tag/111), `FragmentTabHost`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use this project instead of standart.

https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip